# Accessing Gcp secret manager by aws

Tags: google-secret-manager

How to automate AWS access keys for the key rotation to update  in GCP Secrets manager? Is there any service for this automation?

We searched around the google for the documentation we couldn't find any results. Please provide any documentation on this

Comment: Assuming that's the correct tag. If you tag your question with a totally irrelevant tag like "devops", there's quite a big chance that you don't get answers

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation is probably the right tool for this. It allows you to give AWS permission to perform GCP actions without needing to export a service account.